# iTunes Connect TestFlight external testers not receiving invite email

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I have about 120 external testers invited to test my application. Some of them are close friends that have informed me that they had not received an email. Within iTunes Connect next to their name is the word "invited" so it's safe to say iTunes Connect thinks they've been invited.

I tried: having them check their spam folders, deleting them and re-inviting them, trying different email addresses.

Has anyone else come across the same issue/found a fix?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It can only be resolved by external technical support.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. I have contacted support.

Comment: I'd too wish to find out the reason behind this though.

Comment: Same here. It doesn't appear like Apple has really fixed this issue. Can the link to the 'external technical support' be pasted here please? Thanks.

Comment: Same here. When I started in on this iOS app TestFlight seemed like such a cool idea. Now I hate it because we've had so many issues with bugs and things like this not working.

Comment: I hate these rules nazis in here deciding what is a programming question or not.  This is a vital issue that thousands of iOS developers are facing every day and banging their head against the wall.  There needs to be some scope for common sense judgement about the utility of a programming question to actual programmers rather than being driven by OCD librarians who only care about the bloody taxonomy.  The internet is not going to run of space FFS.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Some emails were sent successfully and others were not. I had given my email address also but did not receive the email. It showed "notified" next to my email address but I didn't receive any email address. I removed and added it again. I got the mail this time and the status is "notified" again. :/

Comment: Same here... and totally agree with @gtd

Comment: Does anybody have a follow up on this matter after contacting the support?

Comment: A solution which worked for me was: (1) Turn off the testing, (2) Remove all of the invitees, (3) Turn testing back on, (4) Add the invitees again.

Comment: @NeilLunn (and others with the relevant privilege): Would you please consider voting to reopen this question? It covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" (i.e. iTunes Connect and TestFlight) and is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" (i.e. the development of iOS apps). It has 24 upvotes, 0 downvotes, and a number of comments from other developers seeking an answer. I've had this problem two or three times in recent months and inevitably seem to return here only to experience dashed hopes all over again.

Comment: As with Stackoverflow and Apple, we as mere users are quite obviously "holding it wrong", "using to wrong" and need to "think different". The fact that Testflights email system basically doesn't work and stackoverflow is policed by a number of people who blatantly don't understand what they are policing is of course our fault.